# Overriding core controllers adminhtml issue

Tags: magento-1, overrides, controllers

This is my **xml**:

```
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <mynamespace_mymodule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mynamespace_Mymodule_Adminhtml</mynamespace_mymodule>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

and this is my **controller**:

```
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/controllers/CreateController.php';

class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Adminhtml_CreateController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController
{
    public function loadBlockAction(){
        echo 1; exit();
    }
}
```

I didn't get the echo 1 . What did I do wrong ? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `<mynamespace_mymodule> before="Mage_Adminhtml">` with `<mynamespace_mymodule before="Mage_Adminhtml">`

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <mynamespace_mymodule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mynamespace_Mymodule_Adminhtml</mynamespace_mymodule>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

also your directory structure is must be same after adminhtml folder `Sales/Orders/CreateController.php`

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml') . DS . 'Sales' . DS . 'Orders' . DS . 'CreateController.ph‌​p';

class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController
{
    public function loadBlockAction(){
        echo 1; exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, but now I got this error message: 
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mage/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/controllers/CreateController.php'

Comment: @Chester updated the code `require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Orders/CreateController.php';` check that

Comment: hmmm ,same message

Comment: and it is Order not Orders , but still the same message :)

Comment: @Chester my bad typo mistake thanks for pointing out

Comment: I believed I should use `Mage::getModuleDir` , but i don't know how for `require_once`

Comment: @Chester `require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml') . DS . 'Sales' . DS . 'Orders' . DS . 'CreateController.ph‌​p'` is the syntax you are looking for.

Comment: `Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/rebuildnew/httpdocs/app/code//Controllers/Sales/Orders/CreateController.ph‌​p' `  this is what i got with ur latest update

Comment: @Chester I invert the two parameters sorry I update my answer, 'Mage_Adminhtml' must be the second param

Comment: `require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'Sales'. DS .'Order'. DS .'CreateController.php';`  this  works:D thx a lot !!!